# How to create a password which will reveal a hidden message in html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and js, and I am currently trying to make it so that the user will type in a password, and if correct, it will reveal a hidden message. This is what I got so far. I can't get it to work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="text" id="userInput" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="othername();" />
</form>

<p id="hidden_clue"></p>
```

And here's the js:

```
var pass1 = 3736.62417618;
var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
alert(input);

if (input == pass1) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
}
```

Comment: You're almost close yo do it. That hidden_clue is where you're going to put the value ?

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but on the `getElementById` you need to select the ID of the element that you want to get.

```js
function othername() {
    var pass1 = 3736.62417618;
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

    if (input == pass1) {
        document.getElementById("hidden_clue").textContent = "Hello JavaScript!";
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="password" id="userInput" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="othername();" />
</form>

<p id="hidden_clue"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks great! It's working on stack overflow code snippet testing so it should be good, but for some reason, it won't work on where I'm creating this website. Do you know if this would work on glitch.com?

Comment: @BenDonohue it is working for me  [glitchTest](https://jade-nine-dancer.glitch.me/)

Comment: Oh, nevermind, i got it working. Thanks for the help this was super useful!